# Hibernate- illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions on creating a new Entity Object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

I upgraded Hibernate from 3.4.0 to 4.0.1.
 After migration i am getting error message "illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions".

with stack trace as below:-

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: c; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:418)

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:37)

at net.nationalpayment.cp20.scheduler.CreateEntityUtilityImpl.createTransaction(CreateEntityUtilityImpl.java:123)

at net.nationalpayment.core.scheduler.ProcessMiscSchedule.processMisc(ProcessMiscSchedule.java:153)

at net.nationalpayment.core.scheduler.ProcessDraftSchedule.processDraft(ProcessDraftSchedule.java:287)

at net.nationalpayment.core.scheduler.ProcessEnrollmentImpl.processEnrollment(ProcessEnrollmentImpl.java:154)

at net.nationalpayment.core.scheduler.ProcessEnrollmentImpl.run(ProcessEnrollmentImpl.java:81)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions

at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361)

at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289)

at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1295)

at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:859)

at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor163.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)

at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.persist(Unknown Source)

... 8 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions

at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.setSession(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:112)

at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.reassociateProxy(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:585)

at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.reassociateIfUninitializedProxy(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:545)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.ProxyVisitor.processEntity(ProxyVisitor.java:49)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:124)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.WrapVisitor.processValue(WrapVisitor.java:125)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:76)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.visitCollectionsBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:377)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:279)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:128)

at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)

at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)

at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:725)

at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:701)

at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:705)

at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:853)

... 13 more
```

At very high level, I have an Enrollment Object,Each Enrollment object is executed in a separate thread using executor framework.
Enrollment has one to many relation with various implementations of Schedule. These Schedule object are processed in a loop based on there type. I have specified only 2 use cases (ProcessDraftSchedule and ProcessPrenoteSchedule):-

```
    public void processEnrollment() {
        logger.debug("Inside Process Enrollment");
        Hibernate.initialize(this.enrollment);
        if (!this.em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            this.em.getTransaction().begin();
        }
        try {
            /**
             * This block will get all MISC schedule having status 'SCHEDULED','PENDING','QUEUED' for enrollment
             */
            if (this.transactionMethodWire == null
                    && (this.transactionClass == null || this.transactionClass.equalsIgnoreCase("MISC"))) {
                ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Schedule> miscSchedules = this.dataDao.getMiscSchedules(this.enrollment, date);
                if (miscSchedules != null) {
                    ScheduleProcessorValuesPoolUtil.updateSchedulePicked(miscSchedules.size());
                    this.processMiscSchedule = new ProcessMiscSchedule();
                    this.processMiscSchedule.setEm(this.em);
                    while (!miscSchedules.isEmpty()) {
                        Schedule schedule = miscSchedules.poll();
                        ScheduleProcessorValuesPoolUtil.scheduleList.add(schedule.getSubscriber().getId() + " , "
                                + schedule.getId() + " , " + schedule.getTransactionClassEnum().getDbValue() + " , "
                                + schedule.getAmount().toPlainString() + " , " + schedule.getScheduleStatusEnum());
                        logger.debug("Misc Schedule : " + schedule.getId());
                        this.processMiscSchedule.processMisc(schedule, null);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (this.transactionMethodWire == null
                    && (this.transactionClass == null || this.transactionClass.equalsIgnoreCase("DRAFT"))) {
                ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Schedule> draftSchedules = this.dataDao.getDraftSchedules(this.enrollment, date);
                if (draftSchedules != null) {
                    /**
                     * doing bulk account encryption for clients external
                     * account numbers
                     */
                    SchedulerUtils.decryptExternalBankAccount(draftSchedules);
                    ScheduleProcessorValuesPoolUtil.updateSchedulePicked(draftSchedules.size());
                    this.processDraftSchedule = new ProcessDraftSchedule();
                    this.processDraftSchedule.setEm(this.em);
                    this.processDraftSchedule.setDate(date);
                    this.processDraftSchedule.setAuditLoggerUtil(this.auditLoggerUtil);
                    while (!draftSchedules.isEmpty()) {
                        Schedule schedule = draftSchedules.poll();
                        ScheduleProcessorValuesPoolUtil.scheduleList.add(schedule.getSubscriber().getId() + " , "
                                + schedule.getId() + " , " + schedule.getTransactionClassEnum().getDbValue() + " , "
                                + schedule.getAmount().toPlainString() + " , " + schedule.getScheduleStatusEnum());
                        logger.debug("Draft Schedule : " + schedule.getId());
                        this.processDraftSchedule.processDraft(schedule);
                    }
                }
            }
        this.em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (LockAcquisitionException e) {
        logger.debug("Some error has occured :", e);
        this.em.clear();
        processEnrollment();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Some error has occured :", e);
        ScheduleProcessorValuesPoolUtil.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        /**
         * RollBack Transaction.
         */
        if (this.em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            this.em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (this.em.isOpen() && this.em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            this.em.clear();
            this.em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

All this processing is happening in a single transaction, Supposing the second scenario, which is ProcessDraftSchedule. Here is how the createEntityUtility is invoked.

```
        Transaction transaction = this.createEntityUtility
                .createTransaction(schedule.getEnrollment().getClient().getAccountNo(),
                        new BigDecimal(scheduledAmount), null, null, null, destAccountNum, null, destAccountType,
                        subscriberName, destRoutingNum, null, null, loanAccountType, opt2, null, null, null,
                        this.populateDataDao
                                .getProcessorFamilyId(schedule.getEnrollment(), schedule.getTransactionMethod()),
                        schedule, schedule.getExternalReferenceId(), srcAccountNum, null, srcAccountType,
                        clientName, srcRoutingNum, new Date(), subscriberAddress, null, subscriberName, null,
                        clientSVABalance, null, TransactionClassEnum.DRAFT,
                        schedule.getTransactionMethod(), IdentifyProcessorType
                                .getProcessorType(TransactionClassEnum.DRAFT, schedule.getTransactionMethod()),
                TransactionStatusEnum.NEW);
```

Below is class to get entity object TransactionProcessorType

```
public class IdentifyProcessorType {

    /**
     * This method will return transaction processor type that is used to while
     * creating transaction for schedules
     * 
     * @param transactionClassEnum
     * @param transactionMethod
     * @return
     */
    public static TransactionProcessorType getProcessorType(TransactionClassEnum transactionClassEnum,
            TransactionMethod transactionMethod) {
        TransactionMethodNamesEnum methodNamesEnum;
        switch (transactionClassEnum) {
            case DRAFT:
                methodNamesEnum = TransactionMethodNamesEnum.toEnum(transactionMethod.getName());
                switch (methodNamesEnum) {
                    case DRAFT:
                    case L_ACH:
                        return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            case PRENOTE:
                methodNamesEnum = TransactionMethodNamesEnum.toEnum(transactionMethod.getName());
                switch (methodNamesEnum) {
                    case PRENOTE:
                        return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            case FEE:
                return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
            case MISC:
                return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
            case PAYMENT:
                if (transactionMethod.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Bill Payment")
                        || transactionMethod.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Check - 2 Day")
                        || transactionMethod.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Check - Std")
                        || transactionMethod.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Check - Overnight")
                        || transactionMethod.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Wire")
                        || transactionMethod.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Phone")
                        || transactionMethod.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("P_ACH")) {
                    return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            case TRANSFER:
                return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
            case COMM_PAYOUT:
                methodNamesEnum = TransactionMethodNamesEnum.toEnum(transactionMethod.getName());
                switch (methodNamesEnum) {
                    case ACH:
                        return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
                    case CHECK:
                        return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            case SUB_PAYOUT:
                return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
            case R_FEE:
                return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
            case REFUND:
                return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
            case WITHDRAWAL:
                if (transactionMethod.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("W-ACH")) {
                    return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
                } else if (transactionMethod.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("W-WIRE")) {
                    return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
                } else if (transactionMethod.getName().contains("W-CHECK")) {
                    return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            case COLLECT:
                return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
            case REPAY_LOAN:
                return transactionMethod.getTransactionProcessorType();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

TransactionProcessorType class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSACTION_PROCESSOR_TYPES"

)
@NamedQueries({

        @NamedQuery(
                name = "TransactionProcessorType_getByName",
                query = "select tpt from TransactionProcessorType tpt  where (tpt.name = :transactionProcessorTypeName)"
        )
})
public class TransactionProcessorType implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static String GET_TRANSACTION_PROCESSOR_TYPE_BY_NAME = "TransactionProcessorType_getByName";

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long leadTime;
    private Set<TransactionProcessor> transactionProcessors = new HashSet<TransactionProcessor>(0);

    public TransactionProcessorType() {
    }

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "lead_time", nullable = false)
    public Long getLeadTime() {
        return leadTime;
    }

    public void setLeadTime(Long leadTime) {
        this.leadTime = leadTime;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "transactionProcessorType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<TransactionProcessor> getTransactionProcessors() {
        return transactionProcessors;
    }

    public void setTransactionProcessors(
            Set<TransactionProcessor> transactionProcessors) {
        this.transactionProcessors = transactionProcessors;
    }
}
```

I am getting above mentioned error when i am creating an Entity object(Transaction) as below.

```
public Transaction createTransaction(Long accountNumber, BigDecimal amount, Date checkDate, String checkNumber,
            String description, String dstAcctNum, String dstAddress, BankAccountType dstBankAcctType,
            String dstName, String dstRoutingNum, String externalReference, String memo, String opt1, String opt2,
            String opt3, String opt4, String payerAcctInfo, Long processor_family_id, Schedule schedule,
            String scheduleExternalReferenceId, String srcAcctNum, String srcAddress, BankAccountType srcBankAcctType,
            String srcName, String srcRoutingNum, Date statusDate, String subscriberAddress,
            SubscriberAffiliate subscriberAffiliate, String subscriberName, String subscriberTel, BigDecimal svaBalance,
            String trackingNumber, TransactionClassEnum transactionClassEnum, TransactionMethod transactionMethod,
            TransactionProcessorType transactionProcessorType, TransactionStatusEnum transactionStatusEnum) {
        User user = (User) ScheduleProcessorValuesPoolUtil.valuesPool.get("user");
        Date date = new Date();
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
        transaction.setAccountNumber(accountNumber);
        transaction.setAmount(amount);
        transaction.setCheckDate(checkDate);
        transaction.setCheckNumber(checkNumber);
        transaction.setCreatedBy(user);
        transaction.setCreatedOn(date);
        transaction.setDescription(description);
        transaction.setDstAcctNum(dstAcctNum);
        transaction.setDstAddress(dstAddress);
        transaction.setDstBankAcctType(dstBankAcctType);
        transaction.setDstName((dstName != null && dstName.length() > 45 ? dstName.substring(0, 45) : dstName));
        transaction.setDstRoutingNum(dstRoutingNum);
        if (transactionClassEnum.equals(TransactionClassEnum.COMM_PAYOUT)) {
            Enrollment dummyEnrollment = this.em.find(Enrollment.class, 6L);
            transaction.setEnrollment(dummyEnrollment);
            logger.debug("Dummy Enrollment : " + dummyEnrollment != null ? dummyEnrollment.getId() : null);
        }
        else {
            transaction.setEnrollment(schedule.getEnrollment());
        }
        transaction.setExternalReference(externalReference);
        transaction.setMemo(memo);
        transaction.setModifiedBy(user);
        transaction.setModifiedOn(date);
        transaction.setOpt1(opt1);
        transaction.setOpt2(opt2);
        opt3 = (opt3 != null && opt3.length() > 45)?opt3.substring(0, 45):opt3;
        transaction.setOpt3(opt3);
        transaction.setOpt4(opt4);
        transaction.setPayerAcctInfo(payerAcctInfo);
        if (transactionClassEnum.equals(TransactionClassEnum.ADVANCE)
                || transactionMethod.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Phone")) {
            transaction.setProcessedDate(date);
        }
        transaction.setProcessor_family_id(processor_family_id);
        transaction.setSchedule(schedule);
        transaction.setScheduleExternalReferenceId(scheduleExternalReferenceId);
        transaction.setSecCode(identifySECCode(schedule));
        transaction.setSrcAcctNum(srcAcctNum);
        transaction.setSrcAddress(srcAddress);
        transaction.setSrcBankAcctType(srcBankAcctType);
        transaction.setSrcName((srcName != null && srcName.length() > 45 ? srcName.substring(0, 45) : srcName));
        transaction.setSrcRoutingNum(srcRoutingNum);
        transaction.setStatusDate(statusDate);
        transaction.setSubscriber(schedule.getSubscriber());
        transaction.setSubscriberAddress(subscriberAddress);
        transaction.setSubscriberAffiliate(subscriberAffiliate);
        transaction.setSubscriberName(subscriberName);
        transaction.setSubscriberTel(subscriberTel);
        transaction.setSvaBalance(svaBalance);
        transaction.setTrackingNumber(trackingNumber);
        transaction.setTransactionClassEnum(transactionClassEnum);
        transaction.setTransactionDate(date);
        transaction.setTransactionMethod(transactionMethod);
        transaction.setTransactionProcessorType(transactionProcessorType);
        transaction.setTransactionStatusEnum(transactionStatusEnum);
        this.em.persist(transaction);
        //this.em.

        ScheduleProcessorValuesPoolUtil.updateTransactionsCreated();
        return transaction;
    }
```

I get "illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions" at statement:-

```
this.em.persist(transaction);
```

I am getting this Exception when I try to set

```
transaction.setTransactionProcessorType(transactionProcessorType);
```

The TransactionProcessortType Entity object is kind of readonly object.
Can we have a readonly object shared across multiple Hibernate session ?
 Will be providing more code as required.Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.